# Commons Math: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, apache-commons-math

I have this tiny bit of Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RealVector alpha= MatrixUtils.createRealVector(new double[10]);
        System.out.println(alpha.getEntry(0));      
    }
}
```

I can compile it successfully using `javac Test.java -cp .;commons-math.jar`
But when I try to run it using `java Test -cp .;commons-math.jar`, it throws up this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/ma
th3/linear/MatrixUtils
        at Test.main(Test.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.linear.Mat
rixUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

From the Googling I did, a `ClassNotFoundException` usually occurs when your classpath isn't pointing to the right location. But since my code compiles, I don't see why it shouldn't execute. Any ideas?

Comment: You should have the class file and jar in the same directory

Comment: Try `java -cp "/path/to/commons-math.jar" Test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type java into a command window you actually get how to setup a command to start a class file correctly:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file)

"-cp" is an option so it goes before the class name

So a command script would look like this:

```
java -cp <SEMICOLON_SEPARETE_LIST_OF_LOCATIONS> qualified.path.to.MainClass <ARGUMENTS>
```

Comment: I feel quite silly. Thanks a lot. (Thanks to merlin too)

Answer (score 3):

I just reproduced your problem, and changing the order fixes it for me.

```
java -cp .;commons-math.jar Test
```